# How can I find a specific kind of vendor

Tags: glitch-2011

How do I find what streets have, say, grocery vendors, and even better, which street with a grocery vendor is closest to my location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Zog's Glitchy Tools](http://zoggish.appspot.com/), a collection of data gleaned from the Glitch API. Specifically, the [locations page](http://zoggish.appspot.com/locations) shows details of Vendors, Trees, Resources, etc and clicking on a specific one will tell you the closest location and how to get there from your current location.

Comment: what an amazing app. on appengine even!

Answer (score 2):

There are little icons on the map that show you what types of vendors are on what "streets".